# Where can I find Brian Kernighan's version of AWK that handles Unicode?

Tags: awk

I have heard that Brian Kernighan has released a version of AWK which processes Unicode, but I have not been able to locate it. Where can I find it?

Comment: The Unicode-enabled version  of AWK started to be mentioned online in August 2022. The latest release on Andy Chu's web site is from 6 or 7 years ago, so that can't be it. The arstechnica web site I have seen and it doesn't provide a link to the new Unicode-enable version of AWK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very quick Duck Duck Going gets me https://github.com/andychu/bwk which has pointers to a couple of alternate sources, including https://github.com/onetrueawk/awk with a note that it does not include "build and test changes".

Also https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2022/08/unix-legend-who-owes-us-nothing-keeps-fixing-foundational-awk-code/ which contains a story from August of this year about how Brian Kernighan wanted to contribute his UTF-8 changes to the latter "one true awk" repo but was not familiar enough with Github to produce a proper pull request.

You'll need to clone the repo, then check out the `unicode-support` branch, and see what you get. There's a `README.unicode` with some caveats. Obviously, you'll need to know how to compile and probably debug a C project, probably on a Unix-like platform. The main `README.md` has more detail than is usual for similar projects, but probably still not enough for a beginner to understand the process.

Based on this information, "released" is not really true; he made changes to the source code and made them available. The project maintainer will probably eventually produce a release if the code is robust.

(You'll note that the project maintainer is also one of the primary authors of GNU Awk.)

Comment: Is there any "release" version of AWK with Unicode support? Does GAWK have Unicode support? If no, what's the alternative to AWK that does provide Unicode support?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean exactly. For things like Unicode number support to handle Indic etc number glyphs, maybe look at Perl. There's a legacy tool `a2p` which produces reasonably idiomatic Perl code from simple Awk scripts. The [GNU Awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) mentions Unicode and UTF-8 in a few places, so some sort of consideration is there. If you mean UTF-16 support or UTF-32 support but your requirements are otherwise pedestrian, the simplest solution by far is probably to recode the input to UTF-8 and take it from there.

Comment: @RogerCostello : a full alternative ? none exists, but if you need it, i can share my custom library of unicode functions, plus their byte-level counterparts, that works on basically any awk (e.g. `substrB() ordB() chrB() lengthB() substrC() ordC() chrC() lengthC()`)